# How to pick an ItemViewModel object by LongListSelector Index

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to use the `ScrollTo()` method of a `LongListSelector` to scroll to the top of the list. `ScrollTo()` takes an object, not an index, so I need to feed it the object which is at the top of the `LongListSelector`. I've tried the following:

```
        ItemViewModel topmostObject = (ItemViewModel)App.ViewModel.Items[0];
        MainLongListSelector.ScrollTo(topmostObject);
```

But the `ScrollTo()` method returns an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: can you step through the code and verify `topmostObject` is not null before the call to `ScrollTo()`?

Comment: Yeah, strangely, calling `ScrollTo()` within `if(topmostObject != null)` still causes a NullReferenceException...

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing this in the page constructor? You can't call ScrollTo until the LongListSelector is loaded. (Try OnNavigatedTo or LongListSelector.Loaded event).

Comment: wow, this is brilliant. and mentioned no where else I could find. thank you! BTW, it is the `Loaded` event that worked for me.